# What do I need to change in my code for the modals to work on my log in button?

Tags: javascript, css

I currently have this code for the sign-in button in my website

```
<li style="padding-top:2px;"><button class="btn" style="align:center; width:80px;height:35px;text-align: center;border-radius: 50px;text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 12px;font-weight: 700;" onclick="location.href='buycns.html'">Buy CNS</button></li>
```

I want to use this code for my plug in modals

```
<li><a class="cd-main-nav__item cd-main-nav__item--signin" href="#0" data-signin="login">Sign in</a></li>
```

What do i need to change?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the onclick attribute in the a tag as in the example. This way you can execute the function that displays your modal preventing navigate to the a-link.

The "event.preventDefault();" line prevents the default behaviour of the a tag (ie, navigate to the href link).

After that line, you need to add the code that executes your modal (in the example, replace 'yourExecuteModalFunction' for your own function name and code).

```
<script>
  function yourExecuteModalFunction(event) {
    alert('display modal');
  }
</script>
<li>
  <a 
    class="cd-main-nav__item 
    cd-main-nav__item--signin" 
    href="#" 
    data-signin="login" 
    onclick="event.preventDefault(); yourExecuteModalFunction(event)'">Sign in</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Look now. The line "onclick="event.preventDefault(); yourExecuteModalFunction(event)'" is the key. I don't know the rest of your code, in particular the code that displays your modal. If you share it maybe I can help.